# Python Dilemma this function should be working but it doesn't

Tags: python

I think this should work but doesn't could someone explain me why? the function is expand and should behave as following, given a list of 0 and 1 as input:

```
if input = [1,0,1] -> output = [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]
if input = [1,1,1] -> output = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
if input = [0,1,1] -> output = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
if input = [0,0,0] -> output = [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
ecc.
WHY THE FOLLOWING IS NOT WORKING?

    def expand(a):
      o = []
      t = [0]*2 # t = [0,0]

        for element in a:

          if element == 0:
              t[0] = 1
              t[1] = 0
          elif element == 1:
              t[0] = 0
              t[1] = 1

          o.append(t)

    return o

#Es using expand: input [1,0,1] -> output [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]] 
#instead of [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]] what's wrong?
```

Comment: Isn't your third example wrong? Shouldn't it be `[[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1]]`?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should create t inside the for loop. Now t will always reflect the last time it is changed.

Look at t as a name for a certain piece of memory. Since you don't change the memory-location, you keep on adapting the same piece over and over again

```
for element in a:
   t = [0]*2
   if element == 0:
   #rest of your code
```

Here the memory-location is changed, since you create t anew eachtime

Comment: Thank you :)  now t is re-defined every time.. but I don't anderstand why before was not working..

Comment: @AndreaMengoli: a python variable is a name which refers to a certain memory location. As long as you don't remake the variable the memory location you refer to stays the same.

If you now append that variable to a list a few times, you just append the same memory location to that list.
And since the variable is only one and the same memory location changing this particular variable before appending, will be reflected as well in the previous appends.

By putting the variable definition inside the loop, you ensure that it refers to a new memory location each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ok now I get it!! Thanks a lot Nemelis!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use a temporary list and do it like this:

```
def expand(a):
    o = []

    for element in a:
        if element == 0:
            o.append([1, 0])
        elif element == 1:
            o.append([0, 1])

    return o
```

Another solution would be a list comprehension:

```
def expand(a):
    # if your input values can only be `1` or `0`
    # 'if 0' always evaluates to False whereas 'if any_int_except_zero' always evaluates to True
    return [[0, 1] if element else [1, 0] for element in a]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!